# Share transaction among sessions in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Is this scenario at all possible:

Can we have a group of sessions that share a transaction without the transaction being committed?

Say we have a table employee:

```
   EMPLOYEE

 ID      NAME

 1      Arnab
```

We have a session session1, that updated the row to NAME 'Harry' (not committed)

```
update Employee set Name = 'Harry' where ID=1;
```

At this point, from any other session session2,session3,session4 if we query this table we would still see NAME as 'Arnab' as this transaction is not committed yet.

However, is it possible in oracle to have some sort of 'Grouped' sessions, so that we can have a group of sessions session1,session2,session3,session4 which share the same transaction level, so that, in the above scenario session2,session3,session4 will see the name as 'Harry' even though it was not committed?

However, from some other session not in this group, say session99 the query to the Employee table still gives name as 'Arnab'

I understand that this possible violates the ACID properties of relational databases, and sounds to be a very bad proposition, but right now I am stuck in a database where any kind of code modification is not permitted and this kind of a property seems to be the only situation